# Are Chainlink keepers a security liability?

Tags: solidity, security, chainlink, cross-chain

I've previously read some of Buterin's posts and he's been especially critical of cross-chain bridges. I know they aren't bridges where digital assets are stored non-natively, but are Chainlink keepers a vulnerability since they're performing `checkUpkeep` off-chain? What guarantee do developers have that the code they wrote is being securely and correctly executed off-chain? How resilient is this other chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doe

*Disclaimer: I'm a Chainlink Labs employee.*

**What is "off-chain"?**

To your question regarding what is "off-chain". Off-chain is a synonym for using the blockchain client's simulation capability to tell you what would have happened if you submitted a transaction, without using gas. This uses on-chain data and deployed contracts. There is no other chain as per your question.

How does this work? If we look at Ethereum for example, and other EVM compatible chains, you can simulate a transaction to see what the outcome would be. To do this you need an RPC access node (eg node service providers such as https://www.alchemy.com/, https://infura.io/, or https://moralis.io/) and an Ethereum client such as [Geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/) (see [docs](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/#what-are-nodes-and-clients)). The Geth client allows you to simulate a function from an on-chain deployed contract, such as your Chainlink Keeper-compatible contract, using on-chain data and user supplied inputs and returns what state change that would have happened if you submitted it. This simulation doesn't use gas.

**Breaking this down using Chainlink Keepers**

**Network of Nodes aka Keepers**

In Chainlink Keepers, the Keepers Network is a network of nodes managed by the same DevOps teams that manage the nodes in the Chainlink Data Feeds Decentralized Oracle Network. The Keeper nodes and Keepers Registry are aware of each other through configuration. The Keeper nodes will take turns to monitor and service Upkeeps (jobs) [registered](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/register-upkeep/) on the Chainlink Keepers Registry .

**Off-chain simulation**

The Keepers nodes simulate the checkUpkeep functions (https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/compatible-contracts/#checkupkeep-function) from all the registered Upkeeps (need to be Keepers compatible https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/compatible-contracts/ so nodes know which function to call) and uses the user's checkData (https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/compatible-contracts/#checkdata) supplied on registration, and stored in the Registry, as input into the checkUpkeep function.
If the simulation returns success, the node will take the resulting performData (https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/compatible-contracts/#performdata), if any, from the simulation, do another simulation to see if the performUpkeep function (https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/compatible-contracts/#performupkeep-function) will succeed and falls within the user's specified gas limit (on Registry).

**On-chain execution (or transaction submission)**

If this completes successfully then the Keeper node will submit the performUpkeep transaction on-chain using the performData as input. The Keeper node will make a call via the Keepers Registry to execute the performUpkeep. Once a transaction has been confirmed the Keeper is paid for the gas cost of the transaction plus a premium for monitoring and maintaining the Upkeep (https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/keeper-economics/). This payment happens in the Registry as part of the original transaction call and it is made in LINK. The Upkeep's LINK balance is reduced by the LINK equivalent of the gas cost + premium. Note, the Keeper nodes run Chainlink Labs software that has been optimized for transaction management and can cope with spiking gas environments and re-orgs to ensure your transactions get confirmed.

From the description above you can see the Chainlink Keepers service is fully decentralized. Chainlink Keepers is also highly reliable.

If this is not clear or if I need to elaborate on anything please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Keepers are a bit different.  They just run a function you specify, so there's not really any way for them to be malicious other than just ignoring your request (at which point you (or anyone) can still run the function).  Their oracles would be more of a similar risk since they can change what their putting on-chain (e.g. a bridge is simply an oracle that queries another chain, so if the oracle lies and says something happened when it didn't, parties can lose money).